# make export function that contains dispatch

Tags: export, redux-toolkit, dispatch

I want to make function that I can export it and use it around the project.
The problem is that i need to use dispatch.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { displayMessage } from '../App/store/mixed'

const dispatch = useDispatch()

export const test = () => {


    dispatch(displayMessage({ show: true, text: `test` }));
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(displayMessage({ show: false, text: '' }))
    }, 2000);
}
```

The code above will give you idea what i am trying to accomplish.

Is something like this even doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a thunk:

```js
export const test = () => => (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(displayMessage({ show: true, text: `test` }));
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(displayMessage({ show: false, text: '' }))
    }, 2000);
}
```

which would be invoked like `dispatch(test())` elsewhere.

Or you could also `import` your `store` from your setup file and do `store.dispatch(...)` - but that's a little less clean.

Comment: is it too much to ask add example with store.dispatch(...)  because i am beginner in react so I just want to make it sure I do it right. Thanks a lot you helped me a lot

Comment: It's literally just `import {store} from './someFile'` and `store.dispatch(myAction(..))`, but I'd really recommend to prefer the thunk approach if you can.